# Transfer all settings from corporate laptop to personal laptop?

Tags: domain

I'm using a company issued laptop with windows 7 enterprise joining the company's domain:

Log in: Domain\UserName
Computer Domain: corp.companyname.com (not the same domain mentioned above)

I want to be able to use my personal laptop (Windows 10 Pro: Spectre x 360) as my primary work machine due to hardware limitations of the company issued PC (hp elitebook 8460p), I've managed to use my personal device to log on to the company's VPN server (by installing the same antivirus software and importing certificates from the work machine to my personal one). the problem is that some applications still require user name and password for proxy servers.

my question is: is it possible to make my personal laptop act exactly as the company issued one? by that I mean having the same username and domain settings on my personal laptop, I'm even ready to try out full image installation of the same OS on my personal laptop.

Comment: There are third-party programs that will transfer a user profile to another PC.  Have you tried one of those programs?  Even if you transfer the profile directory contents, you wouldn't be able to connect to the domain, unless the domain administrator added your machine to the domain.

Comment: I know that, and I don't have Domain administration access. is there a way to make the 2 machines identical. (Same computer name with same domain and user settings)

Comment: As @Ramhound mentioned, you will not get the machine connected to the Domain without Domain admin permissions.  From there, just work with your IT team to accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: You really ought to take your personal machine to your domain admin, before joining it to the domain. If you get it on the domain, you'll get your wrists slapped. You would in any place I've worked before, anyway.

Comment: in this case, would it be possible to keep my personal account as another user on the same machine?

Comment: @MagedAhmed - No, there is no way to connect your personal PC to the domain unless the Administrator wants you to connect to it, END OF STORY.  I will not help you bypass restrictions put into place by an IT Administrator.

Comment: As written, this question is off-topic because it is a business question which requires the company's I.T. to be involved to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is possible, because the company has an image, that is going to be windows 7 enterprise, with that, they develop policies for windows and employees certificates which are linked to the domain.

I would say that the only way is to get a copy of the windows 7 enterprise image, which is probably installed on a company server on domain, and after that install the drivers from the official website (brand of the laptop)

They will need to join this on active directory to get the new pc on domain, with few AD policies.

But again, i dont think this is easy since the laptop is not going to be on a list on sccm and they will see that so basically they will deny this for security reasons.